# Can we infer p → (r∧s) from (p∧t) → (r∨s)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is it possible to write p → (r∧s) from (p∧t) → (r∨s) using rules of inference or any other implications in discrete mathematics?

1. (p∧t) → (r∨s)
2. q → (u∧t)
3. u → p
4. ¬s

Need to prove q → r. How do I start with this problem? There's nothing much common between the given premises.

Comment: If you could infer $p\to(r\land s)$ from $(p\land t)\to(r\land s)$ would that mean that you could infer $p\to(p\land t)$ from $(p\land t)\to(p\land t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the first question in your post (and the title of your post):

No, you cannot infer $p \rightarrow (r \land s)$ from $(p \land t) \rightarrow (r \land s)$

Just intuitively: the given statement says that you can know that $r$ and $s$ are both true if you know that *both* $p$ and $t$ are true ... so if you only know that $p$ is true, can you infer $r$ and $s$? Clearly not.

As a concrete example: we can say that someone is a bachelor if this person is male and unmarried: $(m \land u) \rightarrow b$. So, if I tell you that someone is male, is that enough to infer that that person is a bachelor? (i.e. Can we infer $m \rightarrow b$?) Again, clearly not!

So notice that in the alleged inference, we *weaken* the antecedent of the conditional we have, but as a result, the resulting conditional becomes a *stronger* statement, and thus indeed cannot be inferred. Thinking that you can commits the logical fallacy of *weakening the antecedent*.

Now, if you had $(p \lor t) \rightarrow (r \land s)$ as a given, then you *can* infer $p \rightarrow (r \land s)$. Indeed, $(p \lor t) \rightarrow (r \land s)$ is equivalent to $(p \rightarrow (r \land s)) \land (t \rightarrow (r \land s))$, and thus by strengthening the antecedent, we weaken the conditional as a whole, and are therefore dealing with a valid inference called *strengthening the antecedent*

Answer (score 2):

$q$ implies $p\land t$ and hence $r\land s$ (never mind $r$).

Comment: Yes. I wonder if 1 might be a typo for $(p\wedge t)\to(r\vee s)$, which would give exactly $q\to s$ (i.e. without giving the stronger statement $\neg q$).

Comment: There's probably a typo in this question. The premises do not seem to match up with the conclusion.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime If you're right we get $q\to(r\lor s)$, so 4 implies $q\to r$.

Comment: @J.G. sorry, yes, I meant to say "exactly $q\to r$".

Comment: Tip: You do *not* need to use all four premises.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @Adirtha The premises are fine, they *do* entail $q\to r$ as required. (Though they *also* entail $\neg q$.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write p → (r∧s) from (p∧t) → (r∧s) using rules of inference or any other implications in discrete mathematics?

No.  But fortunately you do *not* need to do any such thing.

Hint: You do not need to *use* all four premises in a proof.   If $\alpha, \beta,\gamma\vdash \eta$ then $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\vdash \eta$

- Accept the premises, $(p\land t)\to (r\land s),u\to p, q\to(u\land t),\neg s$.

  - Assume $q$.

    - Now $q$ and premise $q\to (u\land t)$ entails $u\land t$.
    - Of course $u\land t$ entails $u$ and also entails $t$.
    - $\vdots$
    - $p$ and $t$ entails $p\land t$
    - $\vdots$
    - $r\land s$ entails $r$.
  - Obtaining $q\to r$, by discharging the assumption
- Therefore premises $(p\land t)\to (r\land s),u\to p, q\to(u\land t),
  \neg s$ entails $q\to r$.